# “Error response from daemon: Cannot start container … no such file or directory” on Oracle Linux running hello-world

Tags: linux, oracle, docker

TLDR: I am trying to run the hello-world container on a Oracle Linux and I am getting an error message: Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 724ed94d9249b636d6820fb8c2e4ba64232f426812e5b03545762 532751f434e: [8] System error: mkdir /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/724ed94d9249b636d6820fb8c2e4ba6423 2f426812e5b03545762532751f434e/rootfs/sys/fs/cgroup: no such file or directory

I am trying to install and run Docker on a Oracle Linux machine. I have followed the instructions on the Oracle webpage (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E37355/html/section_kfy_f2z_fp.html), but had some problems.

When installing the docker-engine I had some dependencies problem with the UEK packages, but I could solve those with the instructions on this page (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E37355/html/ol_obtain_uek.html).

The docker-engine seemed to run just fine, but when I try to run the hello-world container I got an error:

```
[root ~]# docker run hello-world
Timestamp: 2016-01-13 14:58:06.420677559 -0200 BRST
Code: System error

Message: mkdir /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/724ed94d9249b636d6820fb8c2e4ba64232f426812e5b03545762532 751f434e/rootfs/sys/fs/cgroup: no such file or directory

Frames:
0: setupRootfs
Package: github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer
File: rootfs_linux.go@40

1: Init
Package: github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer.(*linuxStandardInit)
File: standard_init_linux.go@57

2: StartInitialization
Package: github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer.(*LinuxFactory)
File: factory_linux.go@242

3: initializer
Package: github.com/docker/docker/daemon/execdriver/native
File: init.go@35

4: Init
Package: github.com/docker/docker/pkg/reexec
File: reexec.go@26

5: main
Package: main
File: docker.go@18

6: main
Package: runtime
File: proc.go@63

7: goexit
Package: runtime
File: asm_amd64.s@2232
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 724ed94d9249b636d6820fb8c2e4ba64232f426812e5b03545762 532751f434e: [8] System error: mkdir /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/724ed94d9249b636d6820fb8c2e4ba6423 2f426812e5b03545762532751f434e/rootfs/sys/fs/cgroup: no such file or directory
```

Can anybody help me with this?

My knowledge on both Linux and Docker are quite few, so if I forgot to mention any important information please ask!!=o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run Docker on Oracle linux, you need the ["Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel" 3.8 or higher](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/oracle/#prerequisites) installed.

After that, you can follow the [installation procedure in the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/oracle/#install)

Note that kernel 2.6 is no longer supported by Docker since Docker 1.8.0; the last available builds for 2.6 based distro's (RHEL6/CentOS6) is docker 1.7.1

Comment: Thanks for your answer @thaJeztah. I was already using the UEK 3.8 as described at [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E37355/html/section_kfy_f2z_fp.html). I tried the docker 1.7.1 and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/13297) with kernels order than [2.6.32-431](http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/07/docker-centos-6-and-you/).
Reason being:

> "Since it is also not possible to get systemd up on RH6 using lxc."

I tried testing in CentOS6.3 (which is very similar to RedHat/OracleLinux) which had 2.6.32-279.5.2.el6.x86_64 kernel and got the same problem (More information was in the logs).

```
[user@localhost ~]$ docker -v
Docker version 1.7.1, build 786b29d
[user@localhost ~]$ docker run  hello-world
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 6853f515819f8928fa5a9b4f2b2af2c117e2c6183dbc1f9ea59c29a28adc45a8: no such file or directory
[user@localhost ~]$
```

There is however a work around by upgrading your kernel if that is an option. So I upgraded the kernel (2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64) and docker works !

*PS: Do not do this in production systems without testing.*

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum -y update kernel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.crc.dk
...
Dependency Updated:
  dracut.noarch 0:004-388.el6    dracut-kernel.noarch 0:004-388.el6    dracut-network.noarch 0:004-388.el6    kernel-firmware.noarch 0:2.6.32-573.12.1.el6   

Complete!
[user@localhost ~]$ reboot
...
[user@localhost ~]$ uname -r
2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64
[user@localhost ~]$ docker run hello-world

Hello from Docker.
...
For more examples and ideas, visit:
 https://docs.docker.com/userguide/

[user@localhost ~]$
```

So, I recommend you to check if you have an older version of kernel < 2.6.32-431 and do a kernel upgrade and test it out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it did not work. My kernel version is already 2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64. When I run the "yum -y update kernel" command it responds there is no update.

Comment: I have similar issue, but my kernel is 4.1.6-coreos-r1

Answer (score 0):

The kernel you need is kernel-uek, not "kernel".
The normal kernel is RHEL6 compatible and as such it can't have the fixes / updates you need. The UEK kernel works fine.

Consider also uninstalling the RHEL kernel, I just got a case where a kernel update switched back to the normal kernel on reboot. You don't want that to happen :-(

Comment: I installed the kernel-uek as described at the [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E37355/html/section_kfy_f2z_fp.html)  and it did not work with Docker 1.8.0. I changed Docker version to 1.7.1 and it worked.